# Python Get Filepath From Started Process

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, 64-bit

I have problem with getting the path of the executable from the process. I'm using Windoxs XP 64 bit with Python 2.7.5 x86_64 and the code is:

```
pbi = create_string_buffer(200)
size = c_int()

NTDLL.NtQueryInformationProcess.restype = c_int
ret = NTDLL.NtQueryInformationProcess(h_process,  #previously defined
                                      27,
                                      byref(pbi),
                                      sizeof(pbi),
                                      byref(size))

fbuf = pbi.raw[8:]
fbuf = fbuf[:fbuf.find('\0\0')+1]
return fbuf.decode('utf16', errors="ignore")
```

This work on Windows XP 32 bit. Founding in MSDN, I found a dfferent mechanism using 'psapi.dll' and specifically GetProcessImageFileName. This method works on Windows 7 x64 and the code is:

```
PSAPI = ctypes.WinDLL('Psapi.dll')
GetProcessImageFileName = PSAPI.GetProcessImageFileNameA
GetProcessImageFileName.restype = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD
path = create_string_buffer(200)
ret = GetProcessImageFileName(self.h_process, path, 200)
```

Someone has any idea????

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you further elaborate on what your problem is, namely what happens when you run your code?

Comment: I obtain an unintelligible sequence of characters, as though it can't decode correctly the bytes